# Google Ads not working on the Multi-park domain websites

Tags: php, cpanel, ads, adsense

I have developed a multi-park domain website in core PHP and parked every domain using cPanel park API and we have used one template for every domain site and only one Google Ads code is working for every domain site but some domain site Google Ads are not displayed.

For example, we have 300 domain park but ads display on only 130 sites and other sites only display white space (iframe URL generated automatically but ads not display)

Ex: xyz.com - Google ads display in whole site.

Ex: abc.com - Google ads not display in the site.

Note: We have used the same Google Ads code for both sites.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the new Adsense guidelines, you can't add existing code to your new sites any more without AdSense review and approval,  [adding new site here](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9130038).